# how can I write a main for recursive method

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, methods, netbeans

```
long factorial (int x) {

if (x == 0)

return 1; //base case

else

return x * factorial (x – 1); //recursive case
}
```

I have this recursive method for computing x!

I try to write mine for it in NetBeans because I want to see the output for this method but I don't know how to start writing the mine...how can I invoke it in the main to print it?
I hope you can understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use **public static void main(String[] args)** to call the factorial function inside it.

The factorial function must be static because the static function can only reference static functions.

```
// "static void main" must be defined in a public class.
public class Main {
    
    public static long factorial(int x) {

        if (x == 0)
        return 1; //base case

        else
        return x * factorial(x-1); //recursive case
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class calc_factorial {
public static void main(String args [ ]) {


    calc_factorial obj = new calc_factorial( );
    int num = 5; 

    long answer = obj.factorial(num);

    System.out.println("Factorial of " + num + " is " + 
answer);
}
    long factorial(int x){
        if(x == 1)
return 1
else
return factorial(x-1) * x;
        }
    
 }
```